# Changing tab border color at run time in flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

How can I change border color of tab in tab navigator control at runtime? I am trying to access it with its id "mytab" and update it's style.

```
this.mytab.setStyle("bordercolor","red");
```

A TabNavigator has multiple tabs and I have to change style of few tabs based on some logic. StyleDeclaration is applicable for all the tabs under tab navigoter but how can use CSSStyleDeclaration based on componentid?
The only shortfall with this approach is that Style can not be changed for individual tab.

Comment: can you post the mxml part over here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the style directly on the `TabNavigator` won't work. You have to set the `tabStyleName` property on `TabNavigator` and then create a style with the same name, which will be applied to your tabs.  It is the same strategy as [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744097/77926); just set the `borderColor` style instead.

---

If you really need to set the style dynamically at runtime, you can retrieve the `CSSStyleDeclaration` for the tabs and set it like so:

```
  <mx:Style>
    .tabStyle {
      /* define an empty style so there is something to get using getStyleDeclaration */
    }
  </mx:Style>

  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      protected function changeStyle(event:MouseEvent):void
      {
        var cssStyle:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration(".tabStyle");
        cssStyle.setStyle("borderColor", "red");
      }
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>

  <mx:TabNavigator id="mytab" width="200" height="200" tabStyleName="tabStyle">
    <mx:Canvas label="apple" width="100%" height="100%">
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="orange" width="100%" height="100%">
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas label="banana" width="100%" height="100%">
    </mx:Canvas>
  </mx:TabNavigator>

  <mx:Button x="10" y="218" label="Change Style!" click="changeStyle(event)"/>
```

Comment: @Wesely Petrowski Thanks. You are absolutely right. For tab navigator, I have to setup CSSStyleDeclaration first.

Comment: @Wesely Petrowski Is it possible to get Style Declaration of a particular tab in the tab navigator? It it possible based on component  id?