# CSS style specific to an id in flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder, css-selectors

I am trying to change border color of few tabs in TabNavigator based on some logic. I am doing it with the help of following answer:
[Changing tab border color at run time in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772541/changing-tab-border-color-at-run-time-in-flex/9773959)

```
var cssStyle:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration(".MyTabs");
                cssStyle.setStyle("borderColor", "red");
```

But now border color is changing for all tabs with "MyTabs" class. I want to specify it to few tabs with specific ids.

I have tried it to access just one tab by its id but It's not working for me.

```
1. var cssStyle:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("#myTabId.MyTabs");

2. var cssStyle:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration(".MyTabs#myTabId");

3. var cssStyle:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("#myTabId");

4. cssStyle.setStyle("#myTabId.borderColor", "red");
```

Is there way to achieve it?

Comment: #3 should work. Did it have any effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to apply css to an object with a specific id in flex, you can used the advanced css id selector: `#objectid` or `MyTabs#objectid`. [See this adobe resource.](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Advanced+Selectors)

Comment: The ID selector is a basic building block in selectors - nowhere close to being advanced. Silly Adobe and their silly misleading article titles :P

Comment: @BoltClock True, but if the OP wants to search for more information on it, he'll have a lot better luck with the advaned keyword in there.

Comment: @SamDeHaan As per the StyleManager JavaDocs, it only accepts period(.) and type selectors. It doesn't support id selector.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav Hmm. Have you considered changing the `styleName` property of the tabs that need to be changed? have a `.redBorder` (or whatever you'd like to call it) style in your Style block or stylesheet, and then change the appropriate items styleName to that?

Comment: @SamDeHaan Ok. My Tab navigator contains VBoxes. And there is a different css classes for VBox and Tab Navigator. When I say this.myTabId.styleName, It returns me the VBox class.